# Img src doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I wrote this simple javascript code to change an image src using Timeout, but it doesn't work at all. Where is my mistake?

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function titoloanimato()
         {setTimeout (
              function () {document.getElementById("titoloanimato").src = "grafica/titolo_animato_1b.gif"},1000)
         }
    </script>
    </div>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Nothing in that code fragment is obviously wrong.

Comment: Do you ever _call_ `titoloanimato`?

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Check your console for any `errors`

Comment: Add `titoloanimato();` before `</script>`

Comment: Use `document.getElementsByTagName("tagname")[0].src`

Comment: @NabeelSheikh since when is "titoloanimato" a tag ?? o__O

Comment: Post your ENTIRE code in the question

Comment: @Psych Half Sorry my bad...o__O

Comment: Does the image exist in the path mentioned?

Comment: Thank you all! It worked with  Ian Brindley suggest. I was wandering if I should add a "launching" command and... yes, I actually should. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code
**HTML**

```
<div><img src="" id="img" /></div>

<input type="button" value="set" onclick="titoloanimato()">
```

**Javascript**

```
function titoloanimato()
         {setTimeout (
              function () {document.getElementById("img").src = "<image url>"},1000)
         }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RhxZ6/6/